# swagger-2 integration with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a Spring Boot Project running. I want to integrate swagger-2 with the project. I have included all required dependencies and beans and http://localhost:8000/AllergiesConditions/swagger-ui.html#/ loads successfully, but not exactly in a way I need.

**Case 1:** If I keep my swaggerConfig beans like this:

```
@Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.app.allergiesConditions.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/AllergiesConditions/*"))
                .build();
    }
```

Swagger-ui loads as follows:
[image]

**Case 2:** If I keep my swaggerConfig beans like this:

```
@Bean
        public Docket productApi() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                    .select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                    .build();
        }
```

Swagger-ui loads as follows:
[image]

> **Question:** *I want to only see conditions-allergies-controller(Item 3 in Image-2) in my swagger ui. For this what exactly I should write
>   in my swaggerConfig bean??*

Note: As of now in Case-1, there is no loadable controller showing up. The required controllers are located in package: com.app.allergiesConditions.controller and my sample API url is like: http://localhost:8000/AllergiesConditions/api/v1/fetchConsumerDetails

Comment: If you want to exclude some api endpoint then I would suggest you to use `Predicate` in swagger config.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:

Following bean does the job:

```
@Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.app.allergiesConditions.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
```